# How to make a POST request from Flutter to Amplify REST API

Tags: javascript, flutter, express, aws-amplify

Following the [getting started documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#make-a-post-request) for Amplify Flutter REST API, the auto-generated POST request below for ExpressJS results in the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse

The GET request returns fine, but when changing to POST and adding the `body` field below from the documentation the error is returned. How can a POST request be successfully called from Flutter using the Amplify REST API?

**Flutter GET Request - (no error)**

```
Future<void> callAPI() async {
    try {
      RestOptions options = RestOptions(
          path: '/example',
          apiName: 'ExpressJSRESTAPI'
      );
      RestOperation restOperation = Amplify.API.get(
          restOptions: options
      );
      RestResponse response = await restOperation.response;
      print('GET call succeeded');
      print(new String.fromCharCodes(response.data));
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      print('GET call failed: $e');
    }
  }
```

**Flutter POST Request (throws error)**

```
Future<void> callAPI() async {
    try {
      RestOptions options = RestOptions(
          path: '/example',
          body: Uint8List.fromList('{\'name\':\'Mow the lawn\'}'.codeUnits),
          apiName: 'ExpressJSRESTAPI'
      );
      RestOperation restOperation = Amplify.API.post(
          restOptions: options
      );
      RestResponse response = await restOperation.response;
      print('POST call succeeded');
      print(new String.fromCharCodes(response.data));
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      print('POST call failed: $e');
    }
  }
```

**ExpressJS GET request path**

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'get call succeed!', url: req.url});
});
```

**ExpressJS POST request path**

```
app.post('/example', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'post call succeed!', url: req.url, body: req.body})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, notice the reverse slash (\) in your RestOptions' `fromList` arguments.

```dart
RestOptions options = RestOptions(
    path: '/todo',
    body: Uint8List.fromList('{\'name\':\'Mow the lawn\'}'.codeUnits)
);
```

Comment: Those are just to escape the single quotes because the entire string is also wrapped in single quotes. The statement above is equivalent, but I will edit the question with the string directly from the documentation so that it is easier to understand. Both string examples do no work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the github discussion [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/1232) the issue happening due to unneeded escape character.

Change your body parameter to this:

```
body: Uint8List.fromList('{"name":"Mow the lawn now!"}'.codeUnits)
```

or

```
body: ascii.encode('{"name":"Mow the lawn"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Install http package and then:

```dart
import 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> pdf2Text(Uint8List fileBytes) async {
    const path = 'pdf2text';
    final uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost'); // stub uri to create a request

    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      uri,
    );

    request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'file_bytes',
        fileBytes,
        filename: 'file.pdf',
      ),
    );

    final operation = Amplify.API.post(
      path,
      body: HttpPayload.streaming(request.finalize()),
      apiName: 'PDF2Text', // Your api name, get from amplifyconfiguration.dart
      headers: request
          .headers, // Use request headers to get the Content-Type with form data boundary
    );

    final response = await operation.response;

    print(response.decodeBody());
  }
```